# Optimizing transferring of old data to a history table using PHP and mysql

Tags: php, mysql, performance

I am currently in a clean up task, and want to get the history of data's from a mysql table the structure is below. the latest data is with a ID of #5 and #9.

### Current Table

```
ID Employee_ID topic    date_attended
1  7890-1      English  2012-03-24
2  7890-1      English  2013-04-21
3  7890-1      English  2014-02-23
4  7890-1      English  2015-03-22
5  7890-1      English  2016-03-21
6  7890-1      method   2012-04-11
7  7890-1      method   2013-05-02
8  7890-1      method   2014-07-03
9  7890-1      method   2016-09-20
```

I manage to get the latest record by using below query, but this is a very large data (7000 rows) and it took me more than 30 seconds to execute it and get result per `Employee_ID` and added a `ini_set` so i would not get a time out error.

```
$sql = "    SELECT  *
    FROM  `training_database`
    WHERE  ID in (
        SELECT  MAX(ID)
            FROM  `training_database`
            WHERE  `employee_id` = '$id'
            GROUP BY  topic
                 )
    order by  ID ASC
```

";

### Output

Just a example but i got a average of 12 rows per employee_ID and topic

```
ID Employee_ID topic    date_attended
5  7890-1      english  2016-03-21
9  7890-1      method   2016-09-20
```

Now i want to get all the old records and transfer it to a table using the `insert` then `delete` query but it looks like this will be a very long task to execute, i would like to know if there is another way to optimize this process to make it faster "somehow", any suggestions would be great!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming `ID` is the `PRIMARY KEY` of `training_database`:

```
SELECT  t.*
    FROM  
        ( SELECT  MAX(ID) AS max_id
            FROM  `training_database`
            WHERE  `employee_id` = '$id'
            GROUP BY  topic 
        ) AS s
    JOIN  `training_database` AS t  ON t.ID = s.max_id
```

And have this composite index:

```
INDEX(employee_id, topic, ID)
```

If `ID` is not the PK, let's see `SHOW CREATE TABLE training_database` and `EXPLAIN SELECT ...`.

This is a "groupwise-max" problem.  That is a crude solution that does not scale well.  More advanced solutions: http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/groupwise_max

Comment: Thanks sir! now my code is loading for 3 seconds, the imporvement is 200%, i wish i could give you a million point! thanks again!